# .NET project: non existant test breaking the build

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, build, tfs

I have a strange problem: I'm trying to build my .NET project in TFS, but there is a test failing. Problem : it's a test that doesn't exist (to my knowledge) on a controller that doesn't exist!

[image]

So there should be a LeadControllerConstructorTest somewhere in the project but:

- I can't find it
- the LeadController doesn't exist

Does anyone know what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TFS will run tests on all dlls with the word `test` in them.  Check your drop folder for all dlls that contain the word `test` and I would imagine one of them contains the `test` you are seeing.